# Copy values from one void** to another void** in C++ copy constructor

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

I need to copy values in a copy constructor. But my copy constructor doesn't work

```
typedef void* Vptr;

class Vector
{
  int sz;
  Vptr* elemsArray;
public:
  Vector(const Vector& src) : sz{src.sz}, elemsArray{new Vptr[src.sz]} 
  {
    Vptr lp,rp;
    for (int i = 0; i < this->sz; i++) {
       lp = this->elemsArray[i];
       rp = src.elemsArray[i];
       *lp=*rp; // compiler doesn't like this line!!!
    }
  }
};
```

How can copy values without using `std::copy`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing an asterisk and an indirection.

```
Vector(const Vector& src) : sz{src.sz}, elemsArray{new Vptr[src.sz]} 
{
  Vptr *lp, *rp;
  for (int i = 0; i < this->sz; i++) {
     lp = &(this->elemsArray[i]);
     rp = &(src.elemsArray[i]);
     *lp=*rp; 
  }
}
```

Of course the compiler complained, you were trying to copy `void`s. There is no type information to make the copy possible.

I also fail to see why have all the "cleverness" with `lp` and `rp`. Just copy directly:

```
Vector(const Vector& src) : sz{src.sz}, elemsArray{new Vptr[src.sz]} 
{
  for (int i = 0; i < this->sz; i++) {
     this->elemsArray[i] = src.elemsArray[i];
  }
}
```

Comment: Wonderful! You solved my problem in a matter of seconds!

Comment: @MarinRantic - If it does indeed solve your problem, consider marking the checkbox next to the answer.

Comment: Yes I know. But the message appears that i can accept the answer only after 6 minutes